# Passing variable value to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a few things to get this to work, but it's just not working.

I start with this:

```
$('#display_att').click(function() {
        var selected_attribute = $('#first_select2 option:selected').text();
        var attr_value = $('#second_select2 option:selected').text();

        goMap();
   });
```

What I need is for the variables `selected_attribute` and `attr_value` to be available in the function `goMap`.

I tried using a global variable, but that didn't seem to work (assuming I did it correctly).

Comment: pass them to the function like so `goMap(selected_attribute, attr_value);`

Comment: can't you pass them to `goMap()` as arguments

Comment: I recommend to read a [tutorial about functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you will need to structure `goMap` to handle the extra "arguments":

```
function goMap (selected_attribute, attr_value) {
    //do things here
}
```

Then, in your click event send those to variables over:

```
$('#display_att').click(function() {
    var selected_attribute = $('#first_select2 option:selected').text();
    var attr_value = $('#second_select2 option:selected').text();

    goMap(selected_attribute, attr_value);
});
```